# WebGL2 not writing second output of `out int[2]` result

Tags: webgl2

When I read output from the fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
out int outColor[2];
void main() {
    outColor[0] = 5;
    outColor[1] = 2;
}
```

rendered into a 32 bit integer RG texture, I find that only the 5s have been written but not the 2s. Presumably I've got some format specifier wrong somewhere. Or I might be attaching the framebuffer to the wrong thing (`gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`). I've tried varying various arguments but most changes that I make result in nothing coming out due to formats not lining up. It might be that I need to change 3 constants in tandem.

Here's my self-contained source. The output I want is an array alternatingbetween 5 and 2. Instead, I get an array alternating between 5 and semi-random large constants and 0.

```js
let canvas /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ = document.createElement('canvas');
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

let vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `#version 300 es
in vec4 a_position;
void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
}
`);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
console.assert(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), "Vertex shader compile failed.");

let fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
out int outColor[2];
void main() {
    outColor[0] = 5;
    outColor[1] = 2;
}
`);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

let program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-3, -1, 1, 3, 1, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
let positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

let w = 4;
let h = 4;

let texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RG32I, w, h, 0, gl.RG_INTEGER, gl.INT, null);
let frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
let outputBuffer = new Int32Array(w*h*2);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gl.RG_INTEGER, gl.INT, outputBuffer);
console.log(outputBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrayed outputs like `out int outColor[2];` are used for outputting to multiple render targets. In your case, two render targets with one channel each, because you've used a scalar type.

To express a single render target with two channels, try `out ivec2 outColor;`.

Comment: Yup, that fixes it.

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, while you can do `outColor[0] = 5; outColor[1] = 2;` (as you did) for a vector type, you may prefer to write `outColor = ivec2(5, 2);` instead for conciseness etc.